# What happens if I change name of a field in a grails domain?

Tags: java, mysql, grails, grails-orm

I had a grails domain with a field named `created` Though now I've changed it to `dateCreated`. However, my database table still has the column named `created` so anytime I try to save a record grails complains saying `Field 'created' doesn't have a default value` even though I no longer have this field in my domain.

How does one get around this issue? Do I have to open my db and delete this column? In rails this is handled through migrations, what is the equivalent in grails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just rename the domain field, you can specify column name in the mapping block, and not change it when you rename the related field. So, no DB changes will be needed at all.

```
class MyDomain {
    Date dateCreated
    static mapping = {
        dateCreated column: 'created'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specified `dbCreate = "update"` in your DataSource.groovy.

If you are in development stage, you can change it to `dbCreate = "create"` to enable automatic schema refresh. Otherwise, in a production environment, you have to keep that configuration and alter the table manually.

You may refer to [Grails DataSource doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#dataSource), which also proposed some migration tools:

> You can also remove the dbCreate setting completely, which is
>   recommended once your schema is relatively stable and definitely when
>   your application and database are deployed in production. Database
>   changes are then managed through proper migrations, either with SQL
>   scripts or a migration tool like Liquibase (**the Database Migration
>   plugin** uses Liquibase and is tightly integrated with Grails and GORM).

Comment: hmm that seems to work but is there a way to only refresh the schema and not delete the data when `dbCreate` is set to `update`?

Comment: Data will be deleted with dbCreate = "create", not update. But if you want the data to be kept in original schema while also accessible from new domain class, @eugene82 proposed a viable solution:  `static mapping = {
        dateCreated column: 'created'
    }`